# Asp.net: How to call a javascript function at the end of button click code behind

Tags: asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

My motto is to call a Java script function at the end of button click code behind. ie, firstly i need to execute the server side function after which my java script function should get invoked.

**My server side method is as follows**

protected string SaveEmbedURL_click()

{

```
    if (txtembedurl.Text != null)
    {
        School aschool = new School();
        aschool.SchoolId = CurrentSchool.SchoolId;
        aschool.EmbedUrl = txtembedurl.Text;
        SchoolRespository.updateEmbedUrl(aschool);
        return "true";
    }
```

}

**My Java script function is as follows**

function SaveEmbedUrlClientSide() {

```
admin_CustomizeTheme.SaveEmbedURL_click(true);
$('#lbl_embedcode').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
$('#embedCode').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
CopyToClipboard("embedCode");
```

}

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure all you need is to add this

RegisterStartupScript("YourJavaScript", "SaveEmbedUrlClientSide()");

"YourJavaScript" is an arbitrary string that is used to identify the Javascript.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) the relevant MSDN article.

Comment: Thanks conrad. But i think i am missing some parameter while using RegisterStartupScript. Can u explain how RegisterStartupScript should be used in my case?

Comment: RegisterStartupScript, which is Page.RegisterStartupScript is now obsolete so I wouldn't use this method anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`Page.RegisterStartupScript` is now obsolete, so I would use this code.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType, "Javascript", "SaveEmbedUrlClientSide();", true);
```

RegisterStartupScript requires Type, Reference, Code, render script blocks. [Reference Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)